# PowerShell: Testing whether an element exists in web page

Tags: powershell, ie-automation

I am trying to find whether an element exists in a web page:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("http://10.0.0.1")
BrowserReady($ie) # wait for page to finish loading
if ($ie.Document.getElementById("admin")) {
  $ie.Document.getElementById("admin").value = "adminuser"
}
etc, etc
```

(Yes, it is possible for the page at http://10.0.0.1 to NOT contain the element with id "admin" - the why doesn't matter.)

My problem is that the test in line 5 doesn't seem to work correctly: it always returns TRUE whether the element exists or not. I have also tried

```
if ($ie.Document.getElementById("admin") -ne $NULL) {...}
```

with same results.

I am working on a Windows 10 system. Any ideas?

Comment: Hence the test in the `if` statement

Comment: D'oh! I was reading it but thinking it was testing for 'not present'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your comparison. The command `Document.getElementById` is returning with [`DBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which by itself doesn't equals to Null. Therefore, when you execute:

```
if ($ie.Document.getElementById("admin"))
{
   ...
}
```

You'd always returned with `True`. As you can see in the following example, `$my_element` isn't equals to `$null` and its type is `DBNull`.

```
PS > $my_element = $ie.Document.getElementById("admin")

PS > $my_element -eq $null
False

PS > $my_element.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                     
-------- -------- ----                                     --------   
True     True     DBNull                                   System.Object
```

I'd suggest you to use one of this comparisons to determine if "admin" really exists:

```
PS > $my_element.ToString() -eq ""
True

PS > [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($my_element.ToString())
True

PS > $my_element.ToString() -eq [String]::Empty
True
```

If the comparisons return with `True` it means that the value is *Empty* so "admin" is not exists. Of course you can use `-ne` for more convenience.